# how to make auto fill field in wordpress login form using "theme my login" plugin?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, autofill

I have created a login form using  plugin "theme my login" in wordpress. I would like to make a field in login form in which if some one registering as new user then according to provide details of registering user the consequent field must be auto filled if any data match with any previous created user.

For example : There is two field in login form first " Introducer" and second "Introducer ID" if new user filled Introducer "ABCD" and if "ABCD" is already existed in user data as "username" then consequent fieled i.e. "Introducer ID"  will automatically filled by existed User ID form user data base. If That "Introducer" text is not available in user data then error message displays that introducer not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use theme-my-login template in order to add code :

- Copy wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login/templates/login-form.php in your wordpress theme folder root (the plugin will check your theme path before the plugin path).
- Add your code to get your current_user meta data ( check get_user_meta(); )
- Check if user has already this value with WP_user_Query :

  $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'country',
     'meta_value' => 'France' ) );

Hope it will help you !